# Scala tail recursion intersect between 2 lists

Tags: scala, intersection, tail-recursion

I'm pretty new to scala and programming in general (just for fun) and I'm trying to understand tail-recursion and collections but debugg is really hard.

I've 2 lists :

```
val quoters = List[Map[String,List[String]]]

val quoted = List[Map[String,List[String]]]
```

ex :

```
val quoters = List(Map("author1"->List("1","7","8")),Map("author2"->List("2","4","6","3")),Map("author3"->List("5","2","1","3")))
val quoted = List(Map("author1"->List("5","6")),Map("author2"->List("5","8","1")),Map("author3"->List("4")))
```

"quoters" quote "quoted" and "quoted" also quote "quoters".

In the example, :

```
 author1 quoted author2 with "1" and "8",
 author2 quoted author3 with "4",
 author3 quoted author1 with "5" & author2 with "5" + "1"
```

**I want to find circles of "quoters" that quote "quoted" that quote "quoters" ...**

the output should be something like :

```
val quotesCircle = List(
 Map("quoter"->"author1","receiver"->"author2","quote"->"4"),
 Map("quoter"->"author2","receiver"->"author3","quote"->"2"),
 Map("quoter"->"author3","receiver"->"author1","quote"->"1")
)
```

**My problems :**

1/I think I'm misusing collections (it seems too much Json like...)

2/I can get intersection with just List of Lists with :

```
def getintersect(q1:List[List[String]],q2:List[List[String]])={ 
 for(x<-q1;r<-q2; if (x intersect r) != Nil)yield x intersect r
}
```

but not with the structure of List of Maps.

3/I tried this for the recursion but it's not working because ... well i don't really know :

```
def getintersect(q1:List[List[String]],q2:List[List[String]])= {
    def getQuotedFromIntersect(quoteMatching:List[String],quoted:List[List[String]]):List[List[String]]={
     for(x<-q1;r<-q2; if (x intersect r) != Nil)
       getQuotedFromIntersect(x intersect r,quoted)
    }
}
```

I hope I'm clear enough :/

Thank you in advance !

Felix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have one extra layer in your data structures.  And I would probably use the name "authors" instead of "quoted", to avoid confusion because of the assonance between quoter / quoted:

```
val quoters = List(
  Map("author1"->List("1","7","8")),
  Map("author2"->List("2","4","6","3")),
  Map("author3"->List("5","2","1","3")))

val authors = Map(
  "author1" -> List(5, 6),
  "author2" -> List(5, 8, 1),
  "author3" -> List(4))
```

With this in place, and a small function like this:

```
def findQuoters(article: Int): List[String] = {
  quoters.keys.toList filter { name =>
    quoters(name) contains article
  }
}
```

You can then start experimenting with different ways of collecting and reporting who has quoted which author and where, e.g.:

```
// For each name in the 'authors' map:
//    For each article authored by this name:
//        Find all quoters of this article
//        Report that author 'name' has been quoted for article 'id' by 'whom'...

for (name <- authors.keys) {
  for (article <- authors(name)) {
    val qq = findQuoters(article)
    println("author %s has been quoted %d times for article %d by %s".format(
      name, qq.size, article, qq.mkString(" ")))
  }
}
```

which prints output like this:

```
author author1 has been quoted 1 times for article 5 by author3
author author1 has been quoted 1 times for article 6 by author2
author author2 has been quoted 1 times for article 5 by author3
author author2 has been quoted 1 times for article 8 by author1
author author2 has been quoted 2 times for article 1 by author1 author3
author author3 has been quoted 1 times for article 4 by author2
```

Now, think a bit about what you are mapping with these associative arrays.  You can effectively building the adjacency matrix of a graph.  How would you go about finding all circles in a directed graph?

Comment: Hi Giorgos,Thank you. I was stuck with my data structure (yours is much more cleaner...) and yes, I should go for a directed graph. Much more simpler !